# Content provider with multiple joins on same table

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-contentprovider

I'm working with a ListView that has a CursorAdapter and the query is done via LoaderManager to my ContentProvider. Everything seems to work fine, but when I try to do a multiple query with the same table I get a duplicated column error:

table rating:

```
 CREATE TABLE rating ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, message TEXT NOT NULL, 
      from_user_id INTEGER NOT NULL, to_user_id INTEGER NOT NUL);
```

table users:

```
 CREATE TABLE users ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT NOT NULL, 
      avatar TEXT, GENDER TEXT);
```

QueryBuilder:

```
    queryBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    queryBuilder.setTables(rating LEFT JOIN users ON  
    rating.from_user_id = users._id LEFT JOIN users 
    ON rating.to_user_id = users._id );
```

Is there any way to use an alias or any similar approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the `as` keyword to set an alias for a table. Check out https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/join-clause.html and https://www.sqlite.org/syntax/table-or-subquery.html.

Your join clause would look like this:

```
rating LEFT JOIN users as from_users ON rating.from_user_id = from_users._id
LEFT JOIN users as to_users ON rating.to_user_id = to_users._id
```

Actually you only need to set an alias for one of both occurrences of `users`, but setting an alias for both makes it easier to read and understand.

Note that you also need to prefix all columns that come from the `users` table in your projection and all other parts of the query (e.g. `where`, `order by`).

So given that you're interested in the user names of both users (the rating user and the rated user), your projection would look like this:

```
new String[]{"from_users.name", "to_users.name"};
```